How can I skew each side of an element with different angles?
I'm trying to achieve this kind of layout:

This is what I have so far:
I'm just missing the left side to be skewed at a different angle and I'm not sure how to do that without messing up the right side.


  .skew-banner {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #ef4444; /* bg-red-500 */
      padding: 0.5rem 2rem; /* px-8 py-2 */
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.875rem; /* text-3xl */
      font-weight: bold;
      transform: skewX(-20deg);
  }
  .unskew-text {
      transform: skewX(20deg);
      display: inline-block;
  }
<div class="skew-banner">
  <span class="unskew-text">How The Program Works</span>
 </div>




You don't skew sides. You skew elements. Look into how CSS tabs are created. This is a wheel already invented. A pseudo-element with opposing skew could work.

Don't use skew just add triangles at each end using pseudo-elements.

Don't use border triangles, use clip. No, don't use clip, use mask. No, don't use mask, use border-image. No don't use border-image, use sharp overlapped background gradients. No, use SVG. No use perspective transform. No, use …

Use clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%); instead of transform
